# L'article partitif s'utilise le plus souvent avec l'article défini le, la, les, avec lequel il se contracte dans (de) certains cas

Tags: adjectifs, déterminants

> On ne trouve plus cette préposition que dans **certaines** expressions :
>
> L'article partitif s'utilise le plus souvent avec l'article défini le,
> la, les, avec lequel il se contracte dans **certains** cas :
>
> devant **certains** attributs, généralement des noms de métier :
>
> Il a le sens de "une **certaine** quantité" de

([source](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/articles))

Le mot *certain* est un adjectif ici. Pourquoi alors on ne met pas l'article devant *certains* au pluriel alors que l'on le met devant *certain* au singulier ?

Pourquoi *certains* au pluriel se transforme en déterminant pluriel ?

Antodote :

> **certains** : Plusieurs X qui constituent une partie indéterminée d’un ensemble. ***Certains** des rescapés restèrent sur place.
> **Certaines** personnes, poules, voitures*.

Comment: J'ai reçu des réponses ailleurs, mais je ne sais pas si je peux la recopier ici. Si la personne qui a mis une bookmark est intéressée, je pourrai expliquer dans mes mots.